# Is it possible to get share count for a url broken down by country?

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I would like to get share info (share count, like count etc.) from the Facebook Graph API, broken down by country.

I'm currently using FQL via open graph to get overall share counts, but I'd like to break this down by country if possible (e.g. get share count for UK vs. share count for FR etc.). I can't (AFAIK) use Insights for this as I would like to do this for domains I do not own.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible, and how to go about it if so? I'm happy to use FQL or a direct Open Graph call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get this from a public URL.  This will get you a count of the number of likes for a given URL

```
fql?q=select like_count from link_stat where url = 'facebook.com'
```

If you want to know who is liking something, you need to have permissions for the person who owns the post/thing.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/